# Writing custom directive for adjusting height

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to write a `appHeaderResize` directive which measures both the height of the `<app-online-header>` component and the `<app-navigation>` component. Here is the code:

```
  <div class="sticky" appHeaderResize>
    <app-online-header></app-online-header>
    <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  </div>
```

However I'm stuck at how can I access the height of the two components in the directive. How can I access the height from these components from the directive?

Comment: You need a component to access child components. `@ViewChild(AppOnlineHeaderComponent) header: AppOnlineHeaderComponent;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the height of the DOM element in your directive, you can inject the [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) and use it to query the DOM children. Then using [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2), you can set styles, attributes, etc for the elements or access their properties:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHeaderResize]'
})
export class AppHeaderResizeDirective  {
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const arr = Array.from(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes);
    const appHeader = arr.find(node => node.tagName === 'APP-HEADER');
    this.renderer.setStyle(appHeader, 'display', 'block');
    this.renderer.setStyle(appHeader, 'color', 'red');
    this.renderer.setStyle(appHeader, 'border', '2px solid red');
    this.renderer.setStyle(appHeader, 'height', '200px');
    this.renderer.setStyle(appHeader, 'width', '200px');

    console.log(appHeader.style.height); // 200px
  }
}
```

(Note: there are other ways to get the node you want besides looking it up based on the `tagName` (and those ways don't depend on string pattern matching xD). I just used that approach for proof of concept.)

However, if you want to get the component itself, you'll need to use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and nest your elements in a real component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-resize',
  template: `
  <app-header></app-header>
  `
})
export class AppHeaderResizeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(AppHeaderComponent) appHeader: AppHeaderComponent;
  @ViewChild(AppHeaderComponent, {read: ElementRef}) appEl: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.appHeader);
    const height = this.appHeader.height + 'px';
    this.renderer.addClass(this.appEl.nativeElement, 'square');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.appEl.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.appEl.nativeElement, 'height', height);
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.appEl.nativeElement, 'border', '2px solid blue');
  }
}
```

Here is a working app with both approaches: https://stackblitz.com/edit/app-header-child.

Comment: Glad I could help :)